# Load more than 100000 records within 2 or 3 seconds using AngularJS and web API

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to load more than 100000 records using AngularJS with web API. is it possible?

Already I'm using AngularJS Datatable and it is working fine but take more time for loading data.

So I need an alternate solution.

Comment: do you want to load all of them at once?

Comment: You should use pagination. What user would want to read all 100000 at a time

Comment: Load records of what, from where into what? Why might be useful too.

Comment: @devqon agreed but, a user doesn't want to page through 100000 records either, that is at least 500 pages.

Comment: yes its applying DOM (sorting paging and searching) take more time some time UI will be hang

Answer (score 1):

It would be nice to have a look on your code first, but generally speaking, you need to review your approach and ask questions such as:

1. What is the time complexity of retrieving records? Can that be improved (e.g from O(n) to O(log(n))
2. Do I really need to load 100k records? It depends on your application logic but for example for a chat application, I would load the last 10 messages and ask to load another 10 when user scrolls up.
3. Can I benefit by using Promises/Future either in my JS or ASP.net backend? 
   Promises are a very important concept allowing you to run tasks asynchronously.
4. Is my server good enough? This is the least important compared to the above 3 but check the specs such as RAM and CPU. SSD/Flash Drives do tend to run the applications faster.

Comment: +1 for suggestion 2.
About suggestion 1: retrieving/sending/deserializing n records is almost always at least O(n) (unless for instance, you have sparse data and you can send only the non zero ones)

Comment: thanks for your suggestions.